# How load files in a path different than lib (Elixir)

Tags: testing, elixir

I trying to use a helper for a task in a testing. My folder structure is like this:

```
config/
lib/
test/
test/test_helper.exs
test/provider_test/(the test files are here)
```

And now what I want to do is this

```
config/
lib/
test/
test/test_helper.exs
test/provider_test/(the test files are here)
test/provider_test/helpers/(the helpers files... more or less, one for helper)
```

I tried to use this (inside a test):

```
HelperModuler.calling_function(args)
```

But I get this error:

```
 (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function HelperModuler.calling_function/1 (module HelperModuler is not available)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also load the code at runtime for the tests using `Code.require_file` in your test.helpers setup.

```
 Code.require_file("test/provider_test/helpers/helper.exs")
```

Answer (score 14):

To make a module available in all tests, you need to do 2 things:

1. Put it in a file with the extension `.ex`.
2. Add the folder containing that file to the `elixirc_paths` key of the value return from `MyApp.Mixfile.project/0` in `mix.exs`.

For example, here's how Phoenix handles adding `test/support` for just the `:test` Mix env  in `mix.exs`:

```
def project do
  [...,
   elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
   ...]
end

# Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def project do
[app: :example,
 version: "0.1.0",
 elixir: "~> 1.4",
 build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
 start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
 elixirc_paths: ["lib", "path_to_your_src"],
 deps: deps()]
end
```

Add this line `elixirc_paths: ["lib", "path_to_your_src"],` to the return of your `project` function in `mix.exs`